# How to use .replace() for N iterations in Python (Heighway Dragon)

Tags: python

I am trying to substitute every 'a' for 'aRbFR' and every 'b' for 'LFaLb' when given a string such as x = 'Fa'. I have been able to use:

```
y = x.replace('a','aRbFR')
y = x.replace('b','LFaLb')
```

But how do I do this for N iterations?

Thanks for the help!

Edit:
I want this code to continue to replace 'a' and 'b' N times. I want to be able to go through x N times to replace 'a' and 'b'

Comment: What do you mean exactly is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than calling `replace` `n` times, you could use a translation table. In Python 3, you can use the [`maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) method from the `str` class:

```
table = str.maketrans({"a": "aRbFR", "b": "LFaLb"})
```

Which allows you to map the values in a string with the translation table by calling [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html):

```
s = 'Here is a b'
s.translate(table)
# 'Here is aRbFR LFaLb'
```

Comment: Given how unclear the original question is, you answered it quickly and well.

Answer (score 0):

I have just been doing the same question as yours recently. I don't know whether you will answer this question anymore. But, here's what I've got:

```
n = ['F', 'a']
print(len(n))
addNumber = 1
for k in range("InsertNumberOfIteration"):
 for i in range(len(n)+4*addNumber-1):
   if n[i]=="a":
    n.pop(i)
    n.insert(i,"A")
    n.insert(i+1,"R")
    n.insert(i+2,"B")
    n.insert(i+3,"F")
    n.insert(i+4,"R")
   if n[i]=="b":
    n.pop(i)
    n.insert(i,"L")
    n.insert(i+1,"F")
    n.insert(i+2,"A")
    n.insert(i+3,"L")
    n.insert(i+4,"B")
 for j in range(len(n)):
     if n[j]=="A":
       n[j]="a"
     if n[j]=="B":
       n[j]="b"
 addNumber+=1
print(n)
```